# Google App Engine: how to use the internal CSS in the template?

Tags: css, google-app-engine, templates

GAE provides a template system, and we may create a 'base.html', in which an external CSS file (say, 'base.css') may be linked. However, how do I define some internal CSS in an extended html? I don't want to define the CSS in 'base.css' because there are so many extended html files and they may conflict one with another. Right now, I have to do it inside the tag :-(

To be specific:

extended.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
  <style>   <!-- how to do this? -->
    h1 {
      font-family: Arial;
      color: olive;
    }
    h2 {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <h1> ... </h1>
    ...
  <h2> ... </h2>
    ...
  <h1> ... </h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a block in your base.html. Blocks are place holders that can be filled in from extended templates

**Approach1:**

base.html

```
<style>
{% block css %}{% endblock %}
</style>
```

extended.html

```
{% block css %}
  h2 {
  color: red;
}
{% block %}
```

**Approach2:**

base.html

```
<head>
<link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% block css %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

extended.html

```
{% block css %}
 <link href="extended.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% block %}
```